# Taylor Series of $\frac{1}{1-\cos x}$

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

The problem is, as the title suggests, to find the Power Series Expansion of $\frac{1}{1- \cos x}$ around $x=c$.

What I've tried:

- Direct Computation: Derivatives get very ugly quickly, and don't yield a nice formula that I can recognize as a "series."
- Tried finding the integral of $\frac{1}{1- \cos x}$, finding it's series and then differentiating it to get the new series.

  Tried reverse of the above, differentiating and finding it's series, then integrating (very messy).

  Then I tried some substitution "tricks", like using the series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and then plugging in the series expansion for $\cos x$, but that's a double sum that I struggled to produce anything useful from
  :$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n)!}\right)^k$

I am literally at my witts end with this problem. I have spent perhaps a day or two trying to figure it out, because I feel that I am so close - but just barely missing something. I do not want the solution posted - now it's personal and I have to figure it out, but I would greatly appreciate a hint in the right direction, or to point out a mistake that I may be overlooking.

Comment: Is it 1/cos, as in the title, or 1/(1-cos) as in the first sentence?

Comment: Sorry, corrected it - but you beat me to it. It's 1/(1-cos).

Comment: Also, if you want the expansion around the (arbitrary) point $x=c$ it will be very complicated. Are you sure you don't mean to expand around $x=0$? [Looks by your attempts you do mean expand around $0$.]

Comment: $ 1 - \cos x = 2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2} $

Comment: @coffeemath I wish it was indeed expand around $x=0$. But the intent is for the point of expansion to be arbitrary, which understandably makes the problem harder. My attempts may have been flawed in that sense, but I wanted something to start with, and finding it around $x=0$ was one of those "give it a shot." moments.

Comment: @hjpotter92 That was another method that I tried - but I then had to find the expansion of $\frac{1}{2}\csc^2(\frac{x}{2})$ which doesn't play nice around arbitrary points - let alone with anything within my skillset.

Comment: $ \csc^2 x = 1 + \cot^2 x $

Comment: the antiderivative doesn't seem too messy to me

Comment: @user130512 You're right, I mistyped - I'm fixing it right now. Finding it's series was too challenging for me, is what I meant to say.

Comment: Your idea to use the series of $\frac1{1-x}$ isn't correct since this is valid only for $x\to0$ but we have $\cos x\sim_01$.

Comment: If you start from the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{\sin^2 z}$, you can easily get to a power series expansion. However, the coefficients then are given as series, not in a simple closed form, so that may not quite be what you're after. But I don't think you can get the coefficients in a simple closed form, so that's probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 3):

As @hjpotter92 suggest, you have 
$$\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)} = \frac{1}{2\sin^2(x/2)} = -\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(\cot(x/2)).$$
Now you can exploit the series expansion of 
$$\cot(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n 2^{2n}B_{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n-1}, \quad \forall 0<\left|x\right|<\pi.$$ 
Now, by evaluating in $x/2$, differentiating each coefficient and changing the sign, you get
$$\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1} 2(2n-1)B_{2n}}{(2n)!}x^{2n-2}, \quad \forall 0<\left|x\right|<2\pi,$$
where $B_n$ are the [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).

Comment: This works for $c=0$. I don't get anything that doesn't look messy for general $c$. Do you get anything that looks decent?

Comment: actually this series expansion holds $\forall x \in (0,2 \pi)$, because the expansion of $\cot(x)$ holds $\forall x \in(0,\pi)$, and when you substitute $x$ with $x/2$ the $\pi$ becomes $2\pi$

Comment: What the OP means by "around $x=c$" is expanding in a power series in $x-c$; i.e. $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(x-c)^k$$

Comment: Was an initial term $1/x^2$ dropped, since the expansion for $\cot(x)$ begins with $x^{-1}$ which after sign change and derivative would give $1/x^2$?

Comment: I think that in this sense the question is probably not answerable. Anyway, way do you need an expansion of this form, if you already have a series that holds $\forall x$ inside your domain?

Comment: Yes thank you @coffeemath, now I edit

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{1-\cos(x)}=\frac{1+\cos(x)}{1-\cos^2(x)}=\frac{1+\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)}=\csc^2(x)+\csc(x)\cot(x)$

That last one can be easily noticed to be the derivative of
$-(\cot(x)+\csc(x))$. Now the question is a matter of finding the power series expansions of $\cot(x)$ and $\csc(x)$, which are more easily found, and differentiating.

Answer (score -2):

integration of 1/1-cos(x)=
= 1/1-cos(x)(1+cos(x)/1+cos(x) 
= 1+cos(x)/[1-cos(x)][1+cos(x)] 
= 1+cos(x)/[sin(x)][sin(x) 
= 1/sin(x)[sin(x)]+cos(x)/sin(x)[sin(x)] 
= cosec(x)[cosec(x)+cot(x)cosec(x) 
= -cot(x)+cosec(x)+c

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: mst ho to frnds me share kro

Comment: very good answer